# jinja2 rendering empty li

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Just like the title says. Jinja is rendering an extra li tag. Here is my Code.

```
<ul class="list-row">
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ current_user.username }}</a><li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">logout</a><li>
    {% else %}
       <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">login</a><li>
       <li><a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">register</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

and here it is rendered in HTML:
[image: rendered in html]

It's even worse a user logged in:
[image: This is how it looks like when a user logged in.]

Things that I've tried

- single empty li  > it didn't render extra li
- single li with an empty a tag inside > it didn't render extra li
- single li with a tag and url_for > it didn't render extra li
- 2 empty lis (w/ and w/o a tags) > it didn't render extra li

It seems to me that it only happens when I put two li with jinja code. Honestly I can ignore it but it also takes up space.

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, screenshots from your browser's developer console do not reflect the actual HTML being sent over the wire; they're a representation of how the browser has parsed your HTML. (In this case, see my answer, the problem is your HTML is malformed.)

Comment: Thanks! I looked at it once again using view source and it showed the actual html. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how you're closing tags. You have `<li>` where you should have `</li>`, so the HTML gets misparsed.

```
<ul class="list-row">
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
         <li><a href="#">{{ current_user.username }}</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">logout</a></li>
    {% else %}
         <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">login</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">register</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```